# Brackets For Temporarily Connecting Wooden Frames Together?

Tags: woodworking

I am creating a DIY light box for product photography and it will likely be large. So I was thinking about creating the sides so that they can be connected together to form the box and then disconnected so that they are single pieces and could be stacked under the bed.

Can anyone recommend a bracket or hinge to buy or method that would allow me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loose pin hinge has a removable pin so the hinge halves can be separated. Examples

https://shopmtn.eu/products/scenery-fixings-loose-pin-hinge
http://www.doughty-engineering.co.uk/cgi-bin/trolleyed_public.cgi?action=showprod_T61700

and

https://www.ironmongerydirect.co.uk/product/loose-pin-steel-hinge-100x67mm-brass-plated-pair-546135

Comment: Typical interior door hinges, as in the second example here, would be great for larger boxes. They could be installed internally or externally. I'd use one high and one low at each corner. The drawback is that they don't offer diagonal rigidity. That could be achieved with square or triangular plates installed under the pin heads.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something less complicated then dovetail.  I would go with a Half lap joint. [image]

Quicker and easier to assemble and take apart.

No need to buy any mechanical fasteners.

It does not even need to be very tight as the box will be sitting on a flat surface and not being moved much once it set up.

Image is from  [the spruce crafts](https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/wood-joinery-types-3536631)  web site.

OR you could go with [bed frame brackets](https://www.clockworkcomponents.com/product/FIX072-L).